# What's Community Evaluation / Site self-evalution?

Tags: support, privileges

It appears we have a [Community Evaluation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/community-eval), also called "Site self-evaluation", ending in 6 days. What is it, who can participate (how many reputation do you need), what is the data SE gathers used for, and with what interval an evaluation is done?

Comment: Yeah, and how are the questions to be evaluated picked from the much larger lot of all questions?

Comment: @OlinLathrop I dont have all the details, but I know when they have done this on other sites the point is to pick 10 questions at complete random. I believe they are from a pool of questions active in the last year, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I've done it on sites where I have less than 200 rep. I can confirm that it's 10 questions and awards a Custodian badge.